# Global Solution and IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $U = \mathbb{R} ×\mathbb{R}^n$ and for every $T > 0$ there are constants
$M(T), L(T)$ such that
$$|f(t, x)| ≤ M(T) + L(T)|x|, \: (t, x) ∈ [−T, T] × \mathbb{R}^n.$$
Then all solutions of the IVP $\dot{x}=f(t,x), \: x(t_0)=x_0$ are defined for all $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

I assume that this theorem should be proven by Gronwall inequality but I am not sure how. I would appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the equation, one has, for $t\in(t_0,T]$,
$$x(t)-x(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^t\dot{x}(s)ds=\int_{t_0}^tf(s,x(s))ds $$
and
hence
$$ |x(t)|\le |x(t_0)|+M(T)(t-t_0) + L(T)\int_{t_0}^t|x(s)|ds. $$
By [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality), one has
$$ |x(t)\le (|x(t_0)|+M(T)(t-t_0)) e^{L(T)(t-t_0)}.  \tag{1}$$
Suppose that, for some $t_1>t_0$, $x(t_1)$ does not exist, namely 
$$\lim_{t\to t_1^-}x(t)=\infty. \tag{2}$$
One chooses $T$ such that $t_1<T$ and hence (1) holds. Since (1) and (2) are against each other, one concludes that, for the solution $x(t)$ of the IVP, $|x(t)|<\infty$ for each $t>t_0$.

Comment: Your integration seems off, the upper boundary equation is  $\dot u=M+Lu$ so that (setting $t_0=0$)$$M+Lu(t)=(M+Lu(0))e^{Lt}\implies |x(t)|\le |x(0)|+\frac{M(T)+L(T)|x(0)|}{L(T)}(e^{L(T)|t|}-1).$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann, you are right. Thanks